# Issues obtaining Clarke Park transform

Tags: python, transform, electrical-signal

I have a three-phase electric signal and I've been asked to obtain its Clarke-Park transform (also called direct-quadrature-zero or dq0 transformation).

I'm using this Python [library](https://pypi.org/project/ClarkePark/), and I've gotten the tutorial to work, which is the basic process I'm trying to replicate.

My code is quite simple.

```
# Each variable x_r, r, s and t are arrays extracted from files which were given to me
# The arrays hold around 130.000, the x_r one is the timestamp linked to every value, progressing
# in steps of 8.3e-5 seconds

signal_df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': x_r, 'IESTR': r, 'IESTS': s, 'IESTT': t})
signal_df.head()

OUTPUT:
    Time        IESTR       IESTS       IESTT
0   0.000167    584.00769   -765.26831  208.24132
1   0.000250    587.18536   -786.99103  184.07840
2   0.000333    590.26617   -764.24414  171.41190
3   0.000417    631.94775   -742.32513  150.22847
4   0.000500    640.10138   -770.98303  123.43118
```

If I plot this dataframe, I get this graphic (this is a zoomed section of said plot,since the dataframe has around 130.000 records):

[image]

When I try to compute the dq0 values according to said three-phase signal, I end up with a plot which looks like the alfa-beta projection of said original signal.

```
d, q, z = ClarkePark.abc_to_dq0(r, s, t , x_r, 0)

fig = px.line(
    x=wt,
    y=[d, q, z]
)
newnames = {'wide_variable_0': 'd', 'wide_variable_1': 'q', 'wide_variable_2': 'z'}
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name]))

fig.update_layout(
    title="Transformación Clarke (dq0)",
    xaxis_title="Tiempo [Segundos]",
    yaxis_title="Valores transformados"
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

That plot, according to the tutorial and the theory, should look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on what's happening here?